# List posts by category exclude current post

Tags: categories, query-posts, exclude

I'm trying to get a list of posts from one category, echo the title and the permalink of all posts on that category but exclude the permalink and the post name IF the current post is on that list.

It will be displayed on single.php after or inside the loop

Anyone knows if it is possible, if so how?

Thanks in advance

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=MyCatName&showposts=-1'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, note that, since your custom loop is a secondary loop/query, you should use the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) class instead of `query_posts()`. [Read why](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

That being said,

```
/* main post's ID, the below line must be inside the main loop */
$exclude = get_the_ID();

/* alternatively to the above, this would work outside the main loop */
global $wp_query;
$exclude = $wp_query->post->ID;

/* secondary query using WP_Query */
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'MyCatName', // note: this is the slug, not name!
    'posts_per_page' => -1 // note: showposts is deprecated!
);
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );

/* loop */
echo '<ul>';
while( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
    if( $exclude != get_the_ID() ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' .
            get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    }
endwhile;
echo '</ul>';
```

that'll do.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but I got a blank page :(

Comment: You're inserting into single.php, right? Did you wrap the entire above snippet in <?php opening and closing (?>) tags? If implemented correctly, the above will only alter a tiny bit of your post view. It should not influence the whole page. Oh, and see the edit by @Geert - I had missed bracket ( } ). Thanks Geert.

Comment: Yes, I'm cosing the tags, but I get nothing, in fact all after the code stop to work, like the footer and other stuff from the single.php file. You code meant to replace the loop on single.php ? Should I paste the code after or before the loop?

Comment: The last edited code didn't work, Still breaking things, like the footer (it will not load)

Comment: It's **not** meant to replace the main loop. You need to display the other posts in a secondary loop.

Comment: Did you try the code ? is funny but if I remove the get_ on the the_permalink and on the_title the code works as intended, otherwise I breaks all and stop the site to load anything after your code.

Comment: your code says: get_the_permalink() but it should be get_permalink(), That is where the problem was located, That had stopped the blog to load other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Johannes’ code, but using the `post__not_in` argument:

```
/* Secondary query using WP_Query */
$wpse63027_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'category_name'  => 'MyCatName',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__not_in'   => array( get_queried_object_id() ), // Exclude current post ID (works outside the loop)
) );
```

Then you can loop through the new posts:

```
if ( $wpse63027_posts->have_posts() )
{
    while( $wpse63027_posts->have_posts() )
    {
        $wpse63027_posts->the_post();

        // Now do everything you want with the default API calls
        // Example
        the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>', true );
        the_content();
    }
}
```

[WP_Query » Post_*/Page_Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this addition? It's a good suggestion, ain't it?

Comment: @JohannesPille That's what I just did.

Comment: Now this had definitely become the most complete answer to this one. And, @kaiser, there's `get_queried_object_id()` showing up again! I've seen that one once already today, can't remember where. :)